# Import all elements in a specific column from a CSV file given the name of the column

Tags: csv-format

I have a large CSV file with many columns (300 MB). I know their names. I don't know the column numbers. How can I efficiently import a column for inspection by name?

Here is a tiny example file:

```
da = {
       {"column1", "column2", "column3"}
      ,{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}
      , {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}
      , {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}
     };
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "data.csv", da]
```

## question:

> write a function that efficently returns `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` when given `"column2"`

## addendum:

Mathematica has efficient operations for extracting columns by number: `Import[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.csv", {"Data", All, 2}]`

I am curious to know; can I do something similar given the column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
importColumn[file_, columnName_] := Module[
  {columns = Import[file, {"Data", 1}], index},
  index = Position[columns, columnName] // Flatten;
  Import[file, {"Data", All, index}] // Rest // Flatten]

importColumn[NotebookDirectory[] <> "data.csv", "column2"]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

*one possible approach:* (which as Rohit pointed out is inefficient as it requires importing the whole file)

turn the CSV file into a [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and use [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) operations:

```
dataset = Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "data.csv", {"CSV", "Dataset"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
Normal@dataset[All, "column2"]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

A dump save as a `.mx` file can save time for future inspections.

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>"data.mx", dataset];
```

Comment: This requires importing the whole file so it is not memory efficient if there are many columns (as stated in the question).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi good point!